# VB.Net code to run in command prompt

Tags: vb.net, command, prompt

I have a done a VB.Net program that reads the data from two text files ( one text file will contain the list of server names and other will have the list of values) and hit the database with the server name from one text file's list and use the values in other text file as filters.

The code works fine in Dot Net environment.

The requirement is, I need to make it run in the command prompt.Input should be the following

MyProgram.exe -s D:\ServerName.txt -v D:\Valuelist.txt

MyProgram is the name of the program in VB.Net and the other two are text files.

Help me reaching out with this

Thanks,
Ramya

Comment: Is the program a console application? What happens when you try to run it from the command prompt?

Comment: Yes my program is a console application and when I try to run in command prompt by giving MyProgram.exe, it opens the console window but I need to make everything work in command prompt

Comment: OK, are you currently passing parameters into your console application, or are they hard-coded in the application? If they are hard-coded, follow the advice from Michael Rodrigues and Hand-E-Foot in their answers below to pass the parameters into the application from the command line rather than hard-coding those values in your application.

Comment: system.Environment.CommandLine will call the command prompt from vb.net. But my requirement is I need t open the command prompt and I need to call the .net program by passing the arguements.

Comment: I'm struggling to see where the problem is.  To help narrow it down:  Which operating system are you using?  Do you know how to open the command prompt?  Do you know how to navigate the hard drive using the command prompt?  Do you know how to run programs using the command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

To run from the command prompt as you described means that you need to create a `Console Application`.  Selecting this project type when creating a new project means that your program will not have an interface, but instead run on the console.

The command-line parameters will be passed in to the Main event.

You could also use a normal Windows Application, and examine `System.Environment.CommandLine` to see the command-line that was used to start your application.

To test your applciation, specify the command-line attributes you'd like to run with in  Project -> Properties -> Debug -> Command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In the project's properties, under **Application**, set:
**Application type** = Console Application
**Startup object** = Sub Main

Next add a Module to your project (or use an existing one) and create a method similar to:

```
Sub Main(args() As String)
    If args.Length >= 2 Then
        ProcessFiles(args(0), args(1))
    Else
        AskForFiles()
    End If
End Sub
```

This method will be run when the application is executed.  The `args` parameter will contain all command line arguments.

---

Alternatively, you can use a Windows Forms Application, in this case, when it launches, you need to check for command line arguments.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1.Load
    Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If args.Length >= 2 Then
        ProcessFiles(args(0), args(1))
    Else
        AskForFiles()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When we execute the VB.Net code, the command prompt opens and it works. But I need to execute the code from command prompt. I must have to just open command prompt and give the vb.net executable file with two arguements and the corresponding program should execute

Comment: Okay, so what's your problem?  If you go to the command prompt, change to the folder where this program is stored, and type `MyProgram.exe D:\ServerName.txt D:\Valuelist.txt` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it looks like you're actually just running the command from Start Menu > Run (or its variations depending upon which version of Windows you're using).

This means a console window is created for your command to execute in and then it closes.

As a minimum you need to include the argument processing as described in the other answers.

To be able to continue to see the results of your program, either open the Command Prompt first yourself, or add a `Console.ReadLine` at the end of your program. Then it will wait for return to be pressed, or you can just close the window.